# Python / Pandas for loop.. Why is mine so slow?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

So I am new to python, the jupyter environment and pandas.

I've dabbled a little in MATLAB, which is why I've started to lean into Jupyter, python and it's pandas library.

I've managed to set up a largish data frame (1.7millionx9) for some data processing.

I need to detect a fault if an error occurs for 150ms (150 rows), in MATLAB I can do this reasonbly quickly ~few seconds, but in python the following loop takes up to an hour maybe + I haven't had the patience to finish and to me indicates something is wrong with my code?

I'm expecting the same data out as I put in, plus an additional column, which is 0 by default and 1 if TrqSpdQuadrant != UdUq_IqRsQuadrant for 150 rows.

```
PosSpdData['Fault'] = 0
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None # The error for rewriting a column was annoying. <- why isn't this correct?
cnt = 0
for i in range(1, len(PosSpdData['Error_IqRs'])):       
    if (PosSpdData['Error_IqRs'].values[i] == 0):  
        cnt += 1
        if cnt > 150:
            PosSpdData['Fault'][i] = 1  
        else:
            PosSpdData['Fault'][i] = 0
    else:
        cnt = 0
        PosSpdData['Fault'][i] = 0

DemandedTorque  Speed   Ud  Uq  Iq  TrqSpdQuadrant  Uq_IqRs     UdUqQuadrant    UdUq_IqRsQuadrant   Error   Error_IqRs
0   0.0     0.0     0.00000     0.00000     0.0000  0   0.000000    0   0   0   0
1   0.0     0.0     0.00000     0.00000     0.0000  0   0.000000    0   0   0   0
2   0.0     0.0     0.00000     0.00000     0.0000  0   0.000000    0   0   0   0
3   0.0     0.0     0.00000     0.00000     0.0000  0   0.000000    0   0   0   0
4   0.0     0.0     0.00000     0.00000     0.0000  0   0.000000    0   0   0   0
...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...
30302   270.0   847.0   -25.40625   30.75000    461.0625    1   17.162577   1   1   0   0
30303   270.0   847.0   -25.40625   30.75000    463.1875    1   17.099954   1   1   0   0
30304   270.0   847.0   -25.40625   30.75000    463.1875    1   17.099954   1   1   0   0
30305   270.0   847.0   -25.93750   30.75000    463.1875    1   17.099954   1   1   0   0
30306   270.0   847.0   -25.93750   29.34375    463.1875    1   15.693704   1   1   0   0
```

Comment: please provide sample data, perhaps with `numpy.random.randint`

Comment: Keep in mind that MATLAB does a lot of `jit` compilation, which allows you to write iterative code without much of a performance penalty.  `numpy` (and `pandas` on top if) does not do that - it has best performance when using "vectorize/whole-array" methods (that's like older MATLAB versions).

Comment: You should never use for loops with pandas or numpy. That will be very slow. To help you, we need an example of your data and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

This adds 'True' to the 'Fault' column, when n > 150 consecutive rows point to an error, else 'False'

```
PosSpdData['Error_IqRs'] = PosSpdData['TrqSpdQuadrant'] != PosSpdData['UdUq_IqRsQuadrant']
data = PosSpdData['Error_IqRs'].values
PosSpdData['gr'] = np.r_[True, data[1:] != data[:-1]].cumsum()
PosSpdData['Fault'] = PosSpdData.groupby('gr')['Error_IqRs'].transform('sum') > 150
```

---

Benchmark with n = 2_000_000 rows x 2 columns

```
307 ms ± 4.57 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```